# How to union two column tables into complex one by by merging time column?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

For example I've got many tables alike `[VV1]` and `[VV2]` with:

`[TimeStamp]`, `[V1]`

```
2013-12-12 07:00:00.000 3628460,75
2013-12-12 09:00:00.000 3628460,75
2013-12-12 10:00:00.000 3628460,75
2013-12-12 11:00:00.000 3628460,75
2013-12-12 06:00:00.000 3628460,75
```

`[TimeStamp]`, `[V2]`

```
2013-12-12 07:00:00.000 3628460,75
2013-12-12 09:00:00.000 3628460,75
2013-12-12 10:00:00.000 3628460,75
2013-12-12 06:00:00.000 3628460,75
```

and I want to get something alike:

```
2013-12-12 07:00:00.000 3628460,75  3628460,75
2013-12-12 08:00:00.000 NULL        3628460,75
2013-12-12 09:00:00.000 3628460,75  3628460,75
2013-12-12 10:00:00.000 3628460,75  3628460,75
2013-12-12 11:00:00.000 3628460,75  NULL
2013-12-12 06:00:00.000 3628460,75  3628460,75
```

I tried to implement it with joins and my variant is really terrible:

```
select distinct DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), coalesce(VV1.[TimeStamp], VV2.[TimeStamp])) as Date, V1, V2
from vv1
full join vv2
on vv2.TimeStamp = vv1.TimeStamp
```

( DATEDD is UTC to LOCAL time)

It was realized like that because table count is dynamic and everytime when I add new table and want to see new column I can easily edit select string.

But this variant is terrible because it populate double and with more columns it's just goes crazy and distinct is dirty hack to merge...

Now I think about sane and fast realization... How to make it?

Comment: What do you mean by `variant`?

Comment: @bendataclear I mean my try or my version or my wrong code

Comment: Do you have index on Timestamp columns? It may help speed up executing FULL JOIN.

Comment: @semao maybe it's possible to index them but full join without distinct will poplulate lots of additional nodes and there will be a lot of them and it will be really slow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there will be a better performing solution but the query below might be a neater way of doing it, especially if adding new tables:

```
select [Date]
     , MAX([Value1]) as [Value1]
     , MAX([Value2]) as [Value2]

from (
    select DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), VV1.[TimeStamp]) as [Date]
         , V1 as [Value1]
         , Null as [Value2]
    from vv1

    UNION ALL

    select DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), VV2.[TimeStamp]) as [Date]
         , Null as [Value1]
         , V2 as [Value2]
    from vv2 ) subquery

group by subquery.date
```

Comment: what I don't like here is that I need to specify `, Null as [Value2]` things in every union part. if there will be alike 10 columns and I will need to add new it will be really hard.

Comment: but sure this solution is much better compared to my

Comment: If there will be possible anyhow to not repeat `Null as [VX]` that will be ideal method :(